# CATIA-CAA CATKeyboardEvent

Tags: c++, events, keyboard, catia, caa

I know there are only a few CAA Programmers in the world but I try it anyway...

I can't get keyboard events to work. I found this code which looks reasonable but the Notification doesn't fire.

```
AddAnalyseNotificationCB(CATFrmLayout::GetCurrentLayout()->GetCurrentWindow()->GetViewer(),
                        CATKeyboardEvent::ClassName(),
                        (CATCommandMethod)&PROTrvTreeView::OnKeyboardEvent, NULL);

void PROTrvTreeView::OnKeyboardEvent(CATCommand * ipCmd, CATNotification * ipEvt, CATCommandClientData iobjData) {
    cout<< "KeyboardEvent" <<endl;
}
```

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much denser group of developers for CAA at:

http://www.3ds.com/alliances/c-java-developers/forum/

The same question came up, with several people mentioning that this API was unauthorized, and therefore you can't rely on it, even if it works.

The other samples there are essentially the same code as yours, but the only one that purports to work doesn't use `CATKeyboardEvent::ClassName`, but instead uses `CATKeybdEvent`.  Might be worth a try.

Comment: I know about that forum and I hate it, its closed(login required) and you never really get an answer in time. I've read the Questions there and they didn't help, I though i could bring some CAA developers here.